# How can I fix this apk not uninstalling problem in my custom rom?

Tags: applications, operating-system

I like custom ROMs very much. And this problem is regarding issues that I get while uninstalling an app in a specific unofficial rom. Let's start from the beginning:

1. I downloaded this rom from this forum(https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-nicklaus-7-1-2_r29-unofficial-aospextended-rom-v4-6-oms-dui.3790560/)for my Moto E4 Plus(nicklaus_f,xt1770).
2. I booted into my TWRP recovery and wiped the system, data, cache and dalvik. I flashed the rom file, flashed recommended bean gapps mini(mini pack only contains playstore) and after this and booted in rom.
3. It booted fine , no errors and everything was working fine, UNTIL I accidently installed chrome.
4. I wasn't quite worried about chrome because I could easily uninstall it. BUT, when I clicked on uninstall, it started uninstalling but it was unusually taking longer than usual. I waited for 2 mins
   and then my ROM unusually rebooted.
5. After this I flashed the non recommended BitGapps and the same thing happened.

Everything else was working fine . I tried some other ROMs but the same thing happened . So my question was that does it have anything related to stabilization and should I let the ROM stabilize.
And if not , how can I fix this. Yes I havent installed magisk or some other kernel,etc.
Thanks for every reply in advance.

EDIT:This problem only happens when I flash Gapps.

Comment: How did you try to uninstall chrome (from PlayStore, App info, adb shell pm uninstall)?

Comment: I tried to uninstall it through app info.

Comment: Then something is really wrong with your system. Check `adb logcat` but as development of this ROM seems to be dead for a long time I am not sure if there will be a way to fix the problem. May be you should better search for a different ROM.

Comment: How to check adb logcat and can you recommend some Roms because I am not able to find some.(Moto E4 Plus,nicklaus_f,XT1770)

Comment: You install custom ROM and don't know what adb logcat is (-> Google it and learn the basics of Android)? Sorry I don't own that device so I can't recommend anything to you.